# Can a function invoked by a JS Timer call the setData() as returned by React Hooks useState()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

The following is just to fetch the time and display it, and using a JS interval timer to invoke a function to set the state, so as to cause the first `useEffect()` run again to fetch a newer time and update the screen:

```
export default function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({});
  const [timeID, setTimeID] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Los_Angeles")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(dataFetched => {
        setData(dataFetched);
      });
  }, [timeID]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log("INTERVAL", timeID);
      setTimeID(timeID + 1);
    }, 3000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <pre className="data">
        { data.datetime }
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-hawking-fjqnd

It is able to update once (after 3 seconds), but the `console.log()` always showed `timeID` being `0`.  I thought the function is a closure and should be able to successfully call `setTimeID()` and therefore alter the state?

Comment: Change `setTimeID(timeID + 1);` to `setTimeID(timeID => timeID + 1);`

Comment: So what you really trying to do is set an interval to fetch a time update every 3 seconds? That would look like  ```useEffect(() => {
    function updateTime() {
      fetch("https://worldtimeapi.org/api/timezone/America/Los_Angeles")
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((dataFetched) => {
          setData(dataFetched);
        });
    }

    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      updateTime();
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);```

Comment: you mean directly fetching inside of the interval callback?  But what if there are tons of things I do in that first useEffect(), and I need the interval just to have variable (state) change to invoke that first useEffect() and using that variable (state) as a dependency?